# What does 'be overhead by' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

https://www.lexico.com/definition/barren

> ‘In Act Two the barren Lady Kix, lamenting her childless and unfruitful state, is overhead by Touchwood Senior.’

I couldn't find any 'overhead' meaning that is relevant here. Is it a verb here? An adjective? Is it related to some phrasal verb ('head over' or something)?

Googling e.g. 'was overhead by' gives something like this:

> <...> during what she called a private conversation with a reporter that was overhead by other reporters who wrote about it.

which seems to have similar meaning to the Lexico quote; still I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Both instances are typing errors for '**overheard**'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a typo (***overhead*** for ***overheard***).

Comment: Sure, at least the confusion is documented now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. It should be **overheard**.